# Building with iOS 9 features with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ios9

I'm currently beta testing an iOS 9 - only application. I am using external testers with TestFlight.

I need to use Xcode 7 to build my iOS 9 application (the Base SDK in my target in Xcode 6 only has up to iOS 8.4), but when I have uploaded a build for testing,

I get the following **error:**

> External testing is not supported for builds that have been created with a beta version of Xcode, OS X, or iOS.```

Therefore, I need to submit my builds from Xcode 6. My iOS deployment target in Xcode 6 is iOS 9, but, as stated earlier, the iOS 9 SDK is not an option for the Base SDK.

However, apps like Twitteriffic are already deploying iOS9 features, such as `SFSafariViewController`. 
How am I able to set my Base SDK to iOS 9 in Xcode 6 so I can build and submit builds to iTunes Connect? I've already tried to copy over the iOS9 SDK from

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` 
into the corresponding folder in Xcode 6 with no luck. I've read several StackOverflow articles, and none have helped me create an iOS 9 build on Xcode 6 compatible and deployable for testing with TestFlight in iTunes Connect.

If this isn't possible, how can companies already be shipping with iOS 9 features included? It has to be possible to test iOS 9 features prior to the update being publically released.

Comment: What you want to do isn't supported. Try using HockeyApp or Crashlytics instead.

Comment: @AaronBrager thank you, I'll see if HockeyApp will work (I don't see in the docs if you can do pre-release builds, and I need to make sure it works with email invites, not just UUIDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile to an iOS 9 beta device from Xcode 6 -- you really do need Xcode 7. All that is excluded here is Test Flight External Testers during Xcode 7s beta stage, not necessarily the Internal tester and the ability to compile Enterprise Ad Hoc deployment i.e. accessing the IPA through a URL from a registered device.

You can find a SO question on Ad Hoc deployment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment)