# How to install iOS app on client's devices permanently (without time limit)?

Tags: ios, deployment, enterprise

I've built an app for a client and we are currently using TestFlight to Beta test it. Once we finalize the build, I'd like them to have a permanent copy of the app on all their devices. How can I do this?

I've looked into creating an .ipa for "Ad hoc deployment" but this is only valid for up to a year, I believe, so not an ideal solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment?lq=1) discusses Enterprise deployment, and the solution sounds great, but it also appears to use a provisioning profile, so that may mean a time limit as well.

Comment: How many devices do you need to load it on to and do you need to do it remotely? If you can do it all in person why not just upload the app from your computer direct to their devices? Like I said though if you need to distribute it to a lot of people that would not work.

Comment: Hi Stewart, it's just a handful of devices, but installing the app directly to their devices comes with a time limit as well (a year, I think).

Comment: I've never run into problems with time limits. I'm pretty sure that it installs the app just like installing a normal app from the app store.

Comment: Enterprise deployment is made exactly for what you need. There is no time limit on the mobile provisioning profile. The only condition is that the client will need to enrol to the Enterprise Program with apple, and the builds can only be distributed to devices/employees of the company.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, much appreciated. That sounds good. Is the enrolment process a challenge for non-technical people?

Comment: My understanding is that Enterprise distribution requires the user of the app to pay $300/yr, and the app provisioning profile and certificate still need to be manually renewed occasionally or they will expire