# Is it possible to install Android apps from my website, using a simple browser?

Tags: android, download, installation

I want to install from an apk file, downloaded from my website.
(removed iOS as ([Ad-hoc Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment)) answered it.

Comment: You cannot. The files are downloaded to the device, and installed from there. In case of Android, the PackageManager takes care of this, not the browser. You need to explicitly click the .apk file from some file manager.

Comment: I mean when you click a link it downloads them and prompts the install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ad-hoc Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment)

Comment: What information are the other posts missing? Be specific. There are many options for this. Apple's TestFlight, HockeyApp, and Fabric are probably the 3 biggest, Apple's TestFlight being the most restrictive, HockeyApp being the least. `Ad hoc iOS distribution` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Like at (https://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/) but updated, and also (http://builds.io/)

Comment: Yes it's possible. The first link you posted tells how to do it. The post I marked this as a duplicate of tells how to do it. So what's your question?

Comment: The android method.

Comment: I can't collect the device UDID's, any other methods..?