# How can I get developer builds of an iOS app on team members devices remotely?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am working on a remote team. I am the only developer, and the other members of the team are generally non-technical roles (design and management). I am developing the app in flutter, and have very limited experience deploying on iOS.

I want to be able to get development builds (not feature complete or fully functional) of the app on team members devices remotely (I can not just plug their phone into my machine).

Is this possible some way? The amount of people I need to distribute to is only a couple, and they could all be team members to the development account. But ideally the amount of interaction they would need with developer tools should be limited.

Comment: If you upload your build to App Store Connect, you can add your team members to a group of testers and push the app out over TestFlight. https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: I thought testflight requires app review, and incomplete apps will not pass.

Comment: They perform a basic app review, to ensure it complies with various policies, but you can use it for unfinished apps. The first review may take up to 24 hours, but then they’re usually pretty quick after that.

Comment: Otherwise you can collect their device UDIDs and add them to your list of devices in your developer account. You can then use these in a provisioning profile and deploy the builds ad-hoc as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you scared off a correct answer. But it was still correct, so I will repeat it.

Add the users emails as *internal* testers and upload your build to TestFlight. Then they can install and test your app.

No review is done for a build that goes only to internal testers.

I can assure you that this works. Professional Agile development houses use this technique to distribute even very early incomplete builds to clients and QA.

Comment: In the testflight docs it clearly states it must go through app review.

Comment: That is only for external testers. For internal members of the team, the build is not reviewed.

Comment: Whats the difference between internal and external testers? Where is this distinction made?

Comment: Internal members are those who can log into App Store Connect on this same team. They are on your actual dev team.

Comment: Ok. Is the install process still streamlined for internal testers?

Comment: Yes, they just use the TestFlight app on their devices. This is how I distribute  builds to myself, in fact.