# How make my iPad app last forever - without AppStore signing

Tags: ios, ipad, build, certificate

I've developed an app for my iPad, and it builds and installs and runs fine.  But it will only run on the iPad for a week.

Since I don't have an AppStore submission licence - that costs about a hundred dollars (each year, I believe.)  (I'm not certain about their policies).  I can connect my iPad each week and build and install to the device.  But, is there a method to avoid (or automate) this?

The source code never changes, but I guess a new certificate is made an signed - with a different date/time - each build time.  The app is only my personal use and not distributed.

**How can I have it live forever?**

Comment: You can't do it forever. But you can make it last almost a year. You have to create a distribution profile (Ad hoc deployment), linked to your device UUID

Comment: @CZ54 Can you explain more, please?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081180/ad-hoc-deployment

Comment: That requires a paid membership. Without paying the US$99 your app will only run for a week.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [AltStore](https://altstore.io/). According to their GitHub

> AltStore is an iOS application that allows you to sideload other apps (.ipa files) onto your iOS device with just your Apple ID. AltStore resigns apps with your personal development certificate and sends them to a desktop app, AltServer, which installs the resigned apps back to your device using iTunes WiFi sync. To prevent apps from expiring, AltStore will also periodically refresh your apps in the background when on the same WiFi as AltServer.

Comment: The version is only for iOS12.2 and up.  And needs Swift 5 and certificate to build... Won't work for me.

Comment: the altstore works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the source address `https://repo.incendo.ws` after jailbreaking, install the plugin `ReProvision` to realize automatic resign