# How to use XCode Distribute App Development Method

Tags: ios, xcode

when i archive and start to distribute my app in Xcode, there is 4 choice
App Store Connect, Ad Hoc, Enterprice and Development.

i've been wondering how to use the development method, i have upload all the file generated from the xcode to my site but it just return error "The server encountered something unexpected that didn't allow it to complete the request", of course i open the url using safari.

i also have check the box "include manifest for over the air installation" but i have no idea how to use this. most tutorial is only upload to app store or ad hoc. just wondering how this development thingy work

Is there any addition work to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you are actually looking for ad-hoc distribution, however the only difference between that and development is a release build vs a debug build. For an over the air install you actually need to point Safari at the manifest file and make sure that the manifest file points at the ipa. The URL needs to be https and the provisioning profile you have embedded in the app needs to have then device udid for the device you are installing on. All in all, TestFlight is much easier.

Comment: you can refer to this answer for in depth process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588539/3106604

Comment: @Paulw11 but Testflight has its expired date right ? if i use ad hoc or development distribution, will it also have an expired limit ?

Comment: Yes, it does. About the same duration. The only way to get a build that doesn't expire is to install from the App Store.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see, I just want to make a local app for our team, most using android but our boss is using iPhone so there is no way I can skip him. why the hell apple is so restrictive just for making a simple app for local use.

Comment: Probably simplest to just plug his phone into your Mac and install the app directly. You will need to do that every 90 days or so